# Is it ok to delete completed iterations from visual studio online?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, alm

We're using Visual Studio Online with Team Explorer in VS.Net 2013. When managing a work item, the iteration drop down contains a list of all iterations that have ever been defined without taking into consideration the Start and End dates. I would like this drop down to filter out iterations/sprints that have already been completed.

When I go into the management interface and ask to delete an old iteration, I get a message telling me that the work items that were attached to that iteration will need to be reassigned. I'd rather not do that - I want to maintain the historical link between a closed work item at the iteration under which it was delivered.

I'm wondering how others in my situation deal with iteration bloat, or if there is a setting that I'm not seeing.

Comment: I believe you can set permissions on iterations so that they cannot be read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the latest update to VSO Microsoft added the ability to filter the list. However while you can set permissions this can't be used to control visibility.

Most folks categories their iterations by Release which mitigates your issue slightly. The only other option would be to create an iteration that you can dump the ones you don't want to see any more into. If you call it "zzRemoved" it should only ever be right at the bottom.

For example:

```
Release 2014
   |--Release 2014.1
         |--Sprint 1
         |--Sprint 2
         |--Sprint 3
         |--Sprint 4
   |--Release 2014.2
         |--Sprint 5
         |--Sprint 6
zzRemoved
   |--Release 2013
      |--Release 2013.1
            |--Sprint 1
            |--Sprint 2
            |--Sprint 3
            |--Sprint 4
      |--Release 2013.2
            |--Sprint 5
            |--Sprint 6
```

Remember to keep st least the last 10 iterations around so that you get velocity.

Comment: Just to be clear - by 'categorize iterations by release' you mean that they create a release iteration under the project root and then child iterations underneath that for sprints that work toward the release?

Comment: Added example for clarigication